# Is there anyway that I can remove encoded characters from xpath selector in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I require to scrape price from flipkart website but the price comes along special characters is there any possible solutions to avoid this

```py
class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["flipkart.com"]
    start_urls = [
     "https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/topwear/pr sid=clo%2Cash&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen",
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    original_price = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_30jeq3", 
                        " " ))]/text()').extract()
    item['original_price'] = original_price
    yield item
```

Example output: `\u20b9399`

Expected output : `399`

Comment: seems u20b9 is unicode code point for ₹, and remaining is price

Comment: yes i know that is there a way to remove unicode from my output

Comment: Yes you can encode it in ascii `'\u20b9399'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()`

Comment: Replace `extract()` with `re_first(r'[\d.,]+')`